# Insulating value of a specific vacuum

Tags: thermodynamics

The level of vacuum (rough, high, etc) in a vacuum insulating panel determines its insulating value (typically measured in U or R value). Does the VOLUME matter? That is, for the same level of vacuum in an vacuum insulating panel with a thickness of 1 inch, would the performance be altered by being 2 inches thick?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_insulated_panel#Thermal_performance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if any scaffold is present (as is the case in a vacuum insulating panel), a greater thickness produces a better insulative effect, because all materials conduct heat and material thermal resistances increase with increasing distance. One can analyze this using [Fourier's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction#Fourier%27s_law) applied to the material fraction.

If no material is present—straight vacuum—then the distance doesn't matter if one approximates the [view factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_factor) as 1, which is reasonable for large cross-sectional areas compared to the spacing. (Otherwise, one needs to consider the top, bottom, and sides of the evacuated region.)

Comment: How about in a vacuum insulated glass pane-- where there is no "scaffold," as you put it; the difference would be only in the torr value of the vacuum. The VIG panels all have a relatively "thin" evacuated space (1 or 2 mm). Given a vacuum level of say 10 (-3) torr, how much would doubling the thickness add to the insulating value?

Comment: Doubling the thickness of the evacuated space only?

Comment: Yes. The intention here is to find a path to a "sweet spot." The "straight vacuum" in your answer is sometimes straighter than others-- from a rough vaccum of half a mbar to ultra high vacuum at 10(-12) mbar, big difference! The question seeks the sweet spot at which the increased thickness meets the increased hardness of the vacuum to give a maximum insulating value that your average human could actually engineer. Thank you for your interest. I am new to this forum but what a great resource!